# Receive Flow from Room

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I have one question related to the Flow, let's say I have some methods here:

in Dao:

```
fun getIds(): Flow<List<Int>>
```

in my Repository:

```
// which way I should do if I have multiple ViewModels that will 
// need to observe Ids from Room
val ids = dao.getIds()
or
// if I do this way, does that mean everytime I call getRepoIds(), 
// it will create a new flow? (which is kind waste resouces?)
fun getRepoIds(): Flow<List<Int>> = dao.getIds()
```

this really bothers me, and I don't really see any post that talks about this. appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: what you prefer, i would go with the fun (you refer to the same dao.getIds() )

Answer (score 0):

> if I do this way, does that mean everytime I call getRepoIds(), it
> will create a new flow? (which is kind waste resouces?)

This is correct. Though, Room is probably optimized for the `Flow` creation, so it most likely will boil down to a few object instantiations, and the JVM/Dalvik are built with fast object instantiation in mind. This becomes an issue only when getting to thousands of object instantiations.

> which way I should do if I have multiple ViewModels that will  need to
> observe Ids from Room?

If you need multiple ViewModels to access it, and would like to store the flow instance in a variable, you would have to do it in the repository layer, where Room is. And if you do this for multiple models, it becomes boilerplate, hard to read/modify.

In these cases, you would trade a very little performance cost for a very big gain in readability and maintainability. I highly suggest you make the trade and use the functions (`fun getRepoIds()`) directly.

Comment: hi Halex, thanks for replying. and yes, i was planning to put that field flow ```val ids = dao.getIds()``` inside the repository, and then let multiple viewModels to access it. However, to me, that is actually increasing the readability, since i only need to worry about that in one place which is repository. 
however, i might miss something, could you give one example why it will increase readability and maintainability? thanks so much!

Comment: You can think of it as a duplicate symbol, so whenever you change one, you need to change the other, for both name updates and data types. Since you have an interface for the repository/dao (you should), the types need to specified explicitly. When testing the code and implementing a fake repository, you need to mix and match the variables with the functions yet again. Also, the writer of the calling code wouldn't know which one of them to use without a thorough read of the documentation (which means that you have to write it).